# Adding and removing observer issue

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have a view controller "A" which is registered as an observer like this,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"localActionTaken" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveLocalActionNotification:) name:@"localActionTaken" object:nil];
}
```

I am also removing observer in dealloc method.

From view controller "A" user goes to view controller "B" where "localActionTaken" notification is posted.

Everything works fine till this

Now I have another view controller "C" from which user is pushed to view controller "A" and from "A" to "B".
But the issue is in this "C"->"A"->"B", if notification is triggered in "B" then observerver "A" is notified twice!

Please let me know if I am missing here anything.

Note : I am using ECSlidingview and "A" and "C" are top view controllers.

----------------- Update -----------------

I had to move removeObserver to viewWillDisappear based on check for specific view controllers in stack.

Comment: How count called you -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated ?
maybe @"localActionTaken" notification sent twice.

Comment: @Spetruk : No It is sent just once.

Comment: Is it possible that "A" is being registered as an observer twice even if I call "removeObserver" before "addObserver"?

Comment: try it: - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"localActionTaken" object:nil];

}

Comment: @Spetruk : after removing it in viewWillDisappear of "A" how could "A" listen when "B" post notification

Answer (score 1):

Does the number of notifications observed accumulate (grow beyond twice) when navigating between A and B. The viewWillAppear will keep getting called when moving from A <-> B but the dealloc will not be called yet. So perhaps there is something wrong the removeObserver in viewWillAppear that is leading to multiple observers being added on A and this would cause multiple notifications to be observed. The code sample you have included seems to work for adding and removing and in dealloc when popping back to C but I haven't tried with "ECSlidingview"

Answer (score 0):

Add the observer in  `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveLocalActionNotification:) name:@"localActionTaken" object:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An important thing you forgot it is that you need to be `symmetric` in your class.

If you add the notification in the `init` method, you will remove the notification in the `dealloc` method.

If you add the notification in the `viewWillAppear` method, you will remove the notification in the `viewWillDisappear`method (as @Spetruk said in a comment).

So, you can do :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveLocalActionNotification:) name:@"localActionTaken" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; 

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"localActionTaken" object:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: If I remove observer in viewWillDisappear of "A", then I couldn't post notification in "B" as I go from "A"->"B"

Comment: If you want to pass data or make an action from B to A, you should use a protocol and delegate instead of notifications.

Comment: I would have preferred delegation but I have multiple senders.